# Can't create template ado.net files from MDF with Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ado.net

I have spent a `.MDF` file, which I use as a model ado.net in Visual Studio.

The problem is the following :

[image]

No way to update your version? Can someone explain to me why that error occurs and a possible solution? The database was created with SQL Server 2014.

**SOLUTION**

i have use visual studio 2015 with server version update.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply **cannot** do this - you cannot attach/detach or backup/restore (or open) a database from a **newer version** of SQL Server (in your case: 2014 - internal database version 782) down to an **older version** (in your case: 2012 - internal database version 706) - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility.

There's no hack, no workaround, no "black magic" to make this work - it just cannot be done.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.

Comment: But I have on the PC version in 2014 in fact , it is on visual studio that stresses me out with this problem .
There is no way to update the sql server visual studio 2014 ?